# Как сгенерировать приложение React Native Expo, которле будет работать независимо от сервера Expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apk, expo

При генерации апк файла, моё приложение работает только с запущенным сервером Expo, что делать?

Я уже перепробовал многое, и прошерстил все форумы и gpt, но не пришел к результату